modificar rutas de http a https drupal
tengo un problema de visualizacion en varios navegadores, (especialmente Chrome) de mi sitio https://cetam.usm.cl/
esta hecho en drupal y creo que el problema esta en las urls, entonces necesito cambiar de http a https, pero no se onde hacer ese cambio.
Favor ayuda, cualquier consejo y respuesta me sera muy util.
Muchas gracias

Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.
